# Time calculation by using sqlite and Adobe AIR

Tags: sqlite, actionscript, air

Now I'm working on employee  timesheet application by using SQlite and Adobe AIR (Action script). I am struggling to calculate the Time interval calculation from sqlite
 *(i.e every work of an employee should be updated into sqliteDB by hour basis.for example an employee worked  1:50 PM to 3:30 PM, so totally he worked 1 Hr 40 mins).*
My question is, how I can update the time into SQLite and process?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no separate data type for time values, but it can interpret certain strings and numbers as times.

To do computations on time values, you should use *Unix timestamps*, i.e., the number of seconds since 1970.

See [Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for how to convert between this and other formats.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to add time to a database field. You can use SQL only or a combination of SQL and ActionScript. Either way, the first thing you want to do is make sure your database field is set to type DATE. By doing this, your AIR app will be able to SELECT the field as an ActionScript Date( ) object.

Here's an example of adding time to a DATE field named *dateModified* using only SQL. First we'll set the field's date and time, and then we'll add one hour and 30 minutes to it:

```
UPDATE main.Tracking SET dateModified = datetime('2012-11-08 10:00:00') WHERE trackingID = 2;
UPDATE main.Tracking SET dateModified = datetime(dateModified, '+1 hour', '+30 minutes') WHERE trackingID = 2;
```

After executing the second SQL statement, the value of *dateModified* is 2012-11-08 11:30:00.